# Populating a 2D array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to complete a constructor for a particular class in one of my assignments. One thing it needs to do (and what I am having difficulty with) is populating a two dimensional array from a text file.

The 2d array will always be square with dimensions dependant on the length of the rows in the file (something I have defined as "size"). I have successfully populated a one dimensional array from the text file using:

"parseLine(file.getLines().get(0));"

The data I must populate the 2d array with will always be from line 3 downwards. Any help/advice is much appreciated.

[example file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JR0X.png)
[example file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MAhU.png)

Comment: You can use the String.split function, splitting by whitespace and copying the values into your array.

Comment: Something like this?                                                                                                             String[] line = s.split(" ");
        int n = line.length;
        int[] stringToInt = new int[n]; // This is a new array to store int value
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            stringToInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
        }
        return stringToInt;

Comment: Yeah, basically.